# Axios requests fires before Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, es6-promise

So as my question states Axios requests posts some info before Promise.all

So here's the code

```js
newMessages = newMessages.map(message =>
        axios.post(URL, message, {
            auth: { username, password },
        })
    );
    // Axios requests finishes before I call Promise.all, and if I call Promise.all the requests sends second time
    await Promise.all(newMessages);
```

I've tried some other variations but all of them works the same

```js
let sendMessages = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < newMessages.length; i++) {
        sendMessages.push(
            axios.post(
                URL,
                newMessages[i],
                {
                    auth: { username, password },
                }
            )
        );
    }


    // Axios requests finishes before I call Promise.all, and if I call Promise.all the requests sends second time
    await Promise.all(sendMessages);
```

Comment: "*if I call Promise.all the requests sends twice*" - no, that really shouldn't happen. How do you know that each request is sent twice? And what does the rest of your code do?

Comment: @Bergi Well it sends SMS messages, and the code that i shared is the last lines of function that sends notifications to the user. Yes you are right) I guess I've triggered Promises in other way, because instead of receiving 2 SMS, i've received 4. Maybe it was because i was console logging before Promise.all?

Comment: I've actually wanted to say that after i call Promise.all the requests sends the second time) Editted

Comment: I would note that the *"code that you shared"* notably has `newMessages` but the next line is `Promise.all(sendMesages)`. It raises the question that something else might be happening between `newMessages` and `sendMessages`. Certainly the `map()` producing `newMessages` should simply be an array of Promises, which would then be invoked when calling `Promise.all(newMessages)` to return an array of actual results.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yeah It's just a typo) Thank you very much for pointing

Comment: Seems likely to be more than a typo and is merely just what you typed into this question rather than actual code. Again the point here is to please **show how exactly you know this is firing the request before** the `Promise.all()` is reached. This is best done by following the guidelines of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently your question does not do that, and may well be the point you are missing in actually understanding what may be wrong in your actual code.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for explaining next time I will be more careful, so right now I've checked the code, it works as intended

Comment: Why are you using Promise.all(), in your previous line itself you are making all the requests. If you want something to execute only after all calls have been made, then make a promise of results not the calls.

Comment: @Ashmah can you please share code, what do you mean by `make a promise of results, not the calls`

Comment: Sorry, its the same thing. Just executed. @Bergi is right. There are no duplicate calls.

Comment: @NeilLunn No. Promises are not "invoked" by `Promise.all`. They're just awaited.

Comment: @Bergi You're right of course. That was the wrong term